# Locally disabling SonarQ warnings

Tags: sonarqube, pylint, pylintrc

I have a python project configured to amke static analysis with SonarQ.
In tests package, all setUp methods are marked with python:S100 warnings because of method name (it's C0103 in pylint). I would like to disable this for all methods in tests package but I can't find a way of doing it.

It seems you can do this in pylint by putting a pylintrc file inside the packages with the following content:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=C0103,C0301
```

The problem is that sonar is configured to use a specific pylintrc (e.g. the one at project root level), which is the main one, and you can't override properties at package level. Of course I don't want to disable the rule for the entire project.

There is way of doing it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your project to ignore issues raised by python:S100 in some specific directories: see the SonarQube documentation on ["ignoring issues on multiple criteria"](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues).